# How to remove error while using design library?

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

The `app:layout_scrollFlags` has no effect when I use `appBarLayout`

[image]

Comment: have you add this in your layout    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: I have on the outermost layer layout

Comment: And if you use a "normal" toolbar, does it have any effect? From what I know you should have a RecyclerView list and when the list is scrolled up and down, the toolbar will show/hide.

Comment: In fact, I wrote a demo can be achieved, but I moved to my project there is no effect on the

Comment: have you take attrs.xml for your banner

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you add line below into viewGroup:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: I have on the outermost layer layout